# How to get added ,removed files from git remote repository using jgit without cloning? i've tried it with code

Tags: jgit

LsRemoteCommand lsRemoteCommand=  Git.lsRemoteRepository()
    .setRemote(REMOTE_URL).setHeads(true)
    .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("sarathb", "***"));

Answer (score 0):

LsRemoteCommand only mirrors what [ls-remote from git](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) can do, so I think this one can only show the HEADs of branches/tags, but not the contents/changes of single commits.

I would probably [Clone the repository](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepository.java), do the [queries for changes](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowChangedFilesBetweenCommits.java) and remove the local directory again.

An additional optimization would be to use setBare(true) on CloneCommand to not cause the I/O for checking out the files.

Comment: well, i got ref name[ref.getName()]...can i get commit contents using that?

Comment: The snippet at https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/GetCommitMessage.java shows how you can get from a Ref to the RevCommit. The getId() on the RevCommit should be the ObjectId that you need.